# app config settings WEBSITE_CONTENTSHARE in function app deployment slots

Tags: azure-functions, azure-deployment-slots

Do I have to set WEBSITE_CONTENTSHARE value in app settings when having multiple deployment slots? What does this value indicate? Can I provide some random values for WEBSITE_CONTENTSHARE in production and aging slots?

Answer (score 2):

`WEBSITE_CONTENTSHARE` is used along with `WEBSITE_CONTENTAZUREFILECONNECTIONSTRING` which represents where the configurations are stored and the storage account where the function app code is stored.

> Do I have to set WEBSITE_CONTENTSHARE value in app settings when having multiple deployment slots?

You do not need to set the `WEBSITE_CONTENTSHARE` setting in a deployment slot. This setting is generated for you when the app is created in the deployment slot.

> What does this value indicate?

This represents the file path to the function app code and configuration.

> Can I provide some random values for WEBSITE_CONTENTSHARE in production and aging slots?

According to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-recover-storage-account#guidance) "The WEBSITE_CONTENTSHARE setting must be provided and valid at creation time. An automated deployment that doesn't contain these settings results in a function app that won't run, even if the settings are added later."

**NOTE:**

- This is available when deploying to a Windows or Linux Premium plan and Windows Consumption plan.
- This is not supported in Linux Consumption plans and Windows and Linux Dedicated plans.
- If you change or remove this option, your function app may not start.

**REFERENCES:**

1. [App settings reference for Azure Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-app-settings#website_contentshare)
2. [WEBSITE_CONTENTSHARE should not be used accroding to support](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/36458)
3. [Troubleshoot error: Azure Functions Runtime is unreachable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-recover-storage-account#guidance)

Comment: Fyi, when the function host's underlying storage account (AzureWebJobsStorage) network access is restricted, you _[do](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-app-settings#:~:text=There%20are%20scenarios%20where%20you%20must%20set%20the%20WEBSITE_CONTENTSHARE%20value%20to%20a%20predefined%20share)_ need to explicitly provide an existing share name in the deployment template.

Comment: Hi I ran into this issue recently. We have been on the Premium plan for long time without setting WEBSITE_CONTENTSHARE or WEBSITE_CONTENTAZUREFILECONNECTIONSTRING and no issues.  But a recent new app can not run after deploying to Azure.  Do you have any insights?  I am not sure why this is happening now

Comment: @DaisyQL I'm in the same boat, premium plan but after doing a recent terraform deployment, we are having issues with some slots and while troubleshooting, I am getting references to the error of this post. Did you come to a solution?